# Coefficient for the gradient term in stochastic gradient descent (SGD) with momentum

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I'm studying SGD with momentum and have come across two versions of the update formula.

The first is from a wiki same as from the original paper:

$$
\Delta w^t = \alpha * \Delta w^{t-1} - lr * \nabla L(w^{t-1}) \\
w^t = w^{t-1} + \Delta w^t
$$
where $w$ stands for weights; lr stands for learning rate and $\nabla L(w)$ stands for drivatives of loss function.

The second version is more common:

$$
\Delta w^t = \alpha * \Delta w^{t-1} - (1-\alpha) * \nabla L(w^{t-1}) \\
w^t = w^{t-1} + lr*\Delta w^t
$$

My question is: why must the coefficient for the $\nabla L(w)$ term be $(1- \alpha)$?
It seems to me that even if $lr \neq (1- \alpha)$, this would still make sense.
Is there any specific reason to choose this coefficient?

This question is originall post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77006599/coefficient-for-the-gradient-term-in-stochastic-gradient-descent-sgd-with-mome).